# Already dual booting windows and ubuntu but want to install latest ubuntu on another hard drive

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7, hard-drive

so currently I'm already dual booting windows and ubuntu. I've bought a new hard drive where I want to install the latest ubuntu but I want to keep my current setup whilst I make the transition to my new ubuntu installation. After that, I want to delete my ubuntu partition from the dual booting hard drive to just keep windows.

So essentially in the end, I'd end up with 1 hard drive with windows 7 and 1 hard drive with ubuntu. How would I go about doing this? How would I setup grub? I'm very new to this stuff, so any help appreciated.

Comment: Is the drive external (will be removed) or internal? http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Multi_002dboot-manual-config May help setting up manually. Otherwise run the install from LiveCD, and install it onto your drive then do `sudo update-grub`.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just ran the  live cd and installed ubuntu on my new harddrive with all my other hard drives plugged in. I used the advanced options to partition my empty hard drive and installed Ubuntu on it. It did the rest and grub allows me to boot into all os's I have installed.